# How to register a generic type for all of its interfaces

Tags: structuremap

I have a bunch of classes that look something like this

```
public class SlideDefinitionAntiCorruption : 
        ICommandHandler<SlideAssignedToSlideset>, 
        ICommandHandler<SlideRemovedFromSlideset> {
```

I would like all of them to be registered against all of their interfaces.

I currently have

```
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.Scan(s => {
            s.TheCallingAssembly();
            s.WithDefaultConventions();
            s.RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface();
            s.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
        }));
```

this registers it against its first interface but not others.

So how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please note that:
`[Obsolete("ObjectFactory will be removed in a future 4.0 release of StructureMap. Favor the usage of the Container class for future work")]`

there is a method `ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing` of `IAssemblyScanner` interface
you could use it like:

```
new Container(x => {
    x.Scan(s => {
        s.Assembly(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());//by e.g. get entry assembly for scan
        s.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
    });
});
```